# Recommended way of adding daily data to database

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I receive new data files every day.  Right now, I'm building the database with all the required tables to import the data and perform the required calculations.

Should I just append each new day's data to my current tables?  Each file contains a date column, which would allow for a "WHERE" query in the future if I need to analyze data for one particular day.  Or should I be creating a new set of tables for every day?

I'm new to database design (coming from Excel).  I will be using SQL Server for this.

Comment: This is a very broad question. If you are getting a small amount of data daily, then this should be fine. However, the more data you get, the more space you'll need on the database. You will likely want to sit down with a DBA to do a capacity plan and determine the best way to load the data (an automated process using SSIS, perhaps)?

Comment: Well, I will be receiving about 1,000,000 records a day.  Would using "BULK INSERT" from the CSV data file cause problems if the database grew too large?

Comment: 1 million records per day translates into a large sized table very quickly. Even if the table's not very wide, I would highly advise connecting with the database administrator to explain your needs. They can help you with building the appropriate indexes and ensuring that your hardware is capable of handling the volume of data.

Comment: I'll second N West's suggestion to talk to the DBAs. I'm assuming you have dedicated DBAs if you're working with this much data. You'll be creating some maintenance work for them anyway by adding all this data, so it would be good to at least give them a heads-up. There may also be some database design standards in your organization, which you'll want to take into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the structure of the data being received is the same, you should only need one set of tables rather than creating new tables each day.

I'd recommend storing the value of the date column from your incoming data in your database, and also having a 'CreateDate' column in your tables, with a default value of 'GetDate()' so that it automatically gets populated with the current date when the row is inserted.

You may also want to have another column to store the data filename that the row was imported from, but if you're already storing the value of the date column and the date that the row was inserted, this shouldn't really be necessary.

In the past, when doing this type of activity using a custom data loader application, I've also found it useful to create log files to log success/error/warning messages, including some type of unique key of the source data and target database - ie. if coming from an Excel file and going into a database column, you could store the row index from Excel and the primary key of the inserted row.  This helps tracking down any problems later on.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider having a look at [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) (SqlServer Integration Services).  It's the SqlServer tool for doing ETL activities.

Comment: I'm all for SSIS, but I think the question is about how to design the database, not how to get the data there.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, append each day's data to the tables; 1 set of tables for all data.
2. yes, use a date column to identify the day that the data was loaded.
3. maybe have another table with a date column and a clob column.  The date to contain the load date and the clob to contain the file that you imported.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. You most definitely should have a single set of tables and append the data daily. Consider this: if you create a new set of tables each day, what would, say, a monthly report query look like? A quarterly report query? It would be a mess, with `UNIONs` and `JOINs` all over the place.

A single set of tables with a WHERE clause makes the querying and reporting manageable.

You might do a little reading on relational database theory. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) is a good place to start. The basics are pretty straightforward if you have the knack for it.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  I will do some reading on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would have the data load into a stage table regardless and append to the main tables after. Once a week i would then refresh all data in the main table to ensure that the data remains correct as per the source.

Marcus